# How to avoid button click and hover highlight in JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, click, jquery-ui-dialog, highlight

I've got the following problem: I've made an options dialog with, for each row, some text, and a button, which changes state between ON and OFF via a get request to the server.

Whenever i hover on the button, it gets highlighted with its "hover" state, and when i click it, it gets "clicked" state, and then i release the mouse and it gets normal again. That's exactly what I expect, because it's the normal behavior.

But what I want to do, and this is driving me crazy because I can't find it anywhere, is that the buttons won't respond to my mouse hovering, and clicking, and that I can activate or deactivate the "clicked" state with the server response. How would I accomplish this?

I have the following code to initialize the dialog and button:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dlg1").dialog();
        $(".settings_buttons").button();
    });
</script>
```

And the HTML setup of the dialog and button:

```
    <div id="dlg1" title="Global device settings" class="dialog_window">

        <table>
            <form>
                <tr>
                    <td><h2>Setting</h2></td>
                    <td><button id="btn2" class="settings_buttons">OFF</button></td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>

    </div>
```

Comment: It would be good if you give some HTML code.

Comment: See which classes are added dynamically to btn2, then code your logic by removing specific class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have You try to disable a button? It's the fastest but mayby not the best solution just put:

```
<td><button id="btn2" class="settings_buttons" disabled="disabled">OFF</button></td>
```

You should use *disabled="disabled"* for crose browsers result.

Comment: I have tried it, but I don't get the desired result because I use multiple selectable themes, anyway i put the Enabled/Disabled state in  a separate image now. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a style for all buttons like this:

```
.dupe{
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.16, rgb(207,207,207)),
    color-stop(0.79, rgb(252,252,252))
);
     background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(207,207,207) 16%,
    rgb(252,252,252) 79%
);
padding:0px;
border:1px solid #6e6b6b;}
```

​See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mg2zb/1/)